# Python3 tkinter is it possible to make the frame able to be clicked through?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a small little tracker window with some timers and I would love to be able to make it click-through. I have yet not been able to find any solution to this problem. The window itself is created, and the timers are working. The only thing I can't figure out is if it is possible to make the window click-through. I am using the tkinter package.

My code is available here: http://pastebin.com/qSFZqpQ6 - It is a bit messy, as I am new to Python, so I could probably definitely work on my setup.

Code from link

```
import win32api
import time
from tkinter import *

input = "0.00"
counter = time.clock()

flaskmult = 1.11

positionX = 2300
positionY = 1100

witchfireTime = 6
dyingrumiTime = 4.8
basaltTime = 7.9

activeTime = False
started = False

def keyWasUnPressed():
    global counter
    counter = time.clock()
    global started
    started = True


def isKeyPressed(key):
    #"if the high-order bit is 1, the key is down; otherwise, it is up."
    return (win32api.GetKeyState(key) & (1 << 7)) != 0

root = Tk()

root.title("Flasktracker")
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("+"+str(positionX)+"+"+str(positionY))
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

labelText = StringVar()
label = Label(root,textvariable=labelText, relief=FLAT, font = "Helvetica 36 bold italic").grid(row=0, column=0)
labelText.set("Witchfire: ")

labelText2 = StringVar()
label2 = Label(root,textvariable=labelText2, relief=FLAT, font = "Helvetica 36 bold italic").grid(row=0, column=1)
labelText2.set(input)

labelText3 = StringVar()
label3 = Label(root,textvariable=labelText3, relief=FLAT, font = "Helvetica 36 bold italic").grid(row=1, column=0)
labelText3.set("Dying/Rumi: ")

labelText4 = StringVar()
label4 = Label(root,textvariable=labelText4, relief=FLAT, font = "Helvetica 36 bold italic").grid(row=1, column=1)
labelText4.set(input)

labelText5 = StringVar()
label5 = Label(root,textvariable=labelText5, relief=FLAT, font = "Helvetica 36 bold italic").grid(row=2, column=0)
labelText5.set("Basalt: ")

labelText6 = StringVar()
label6 = Label(root,textvariable=labelText6, relief=FLAT, font = "Helvetica 36 bold italic").grid(row=2, column=1)
labelText6.set(input)

key = ord('1')

wasKeyPressedTheLastTimeWeChecked = False

def calcTime(timer):
    return (timer*flaskmult)-(time.clock()-counter)

while True:
    keyIsPressed = isKeyPressed(key)
    if not keyIsPressed and wasKeyPressedTheLastTimeWeChecked:
        keyWasUnPressed()
    wasKeyPressedTheLastTimeWeChecked = keyIsPressed
    activeTime = False
    if started and calcTime(witchfireTime)>0:
        labelText2.set('{:0.2f}'.format(calcTime(witchfireTime)))
        activeTime = True
    else:
        labelText2.set("0.00")
    if started and calcTime(dyingrumiTime)>0:
        labelText4.set('{:0.2f}'.format(calcTime(dyingrumiTime)))
        activeTime = True
    else:
        labelText4.set("0.00")
    if started and calcTime(basaltTime)>0:
        labelText6.set('{:0.2f}'.format(calcTime(basaltTime)))
        activeTime = True
    else:
        labelText6.set("0.00")
    if activeTime:
        root.attributes('-alpha',1)
    else:
        root.attributes('-alpha',0)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
```

Comment: What exactly does clicked through mean? Is it a Windows only concept?

Comment: You don't need to call both  `update` and `update_idletasks`. The latter just does a subset of what the former does.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible To do this with tkinter. It might be possible to do that with a healthy amount of platform-specific extensions, but if you go that route you might as well just write a native solution without tkinter.